# Is there a way to provide docker-compose env-file from stdin?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

In docker run one can do

```
docker run --env-file <(env | grep ^APP_) ...
```

Is there a similar way for docker-compose?
I would like to avoid physical env file.

Comment: You can use `--env-file` as an option to `docker-compose` too, it is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option). You could try but I am not sure it works because in my experience `docker-compose` does not like env files unless the file is called `.env`, but maybe I was just unlucky.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara unfortunately compose does not accept non-physical input `ERROR: /dev/fd/63 is not a file.`

Comment: I came here after trying the following suggestion that is similar to this question without success: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7326#issuecomment-1252426491. The upvotes on the comment suggests that it works for some people (maybe in particular versions?).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of --env-file option of the docker cli in docker-compose is the `env_file` configuration option in the docker-compose file. But I think this requires a physical .env file.

If you want use the environment variables of your host machine, you can define them in docker-compose (with an optional fallback value):

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    image: myapp
    environment:
    - APP_MYVAR=${APP_MYVAR-fallbackvalue}
```

It's not so convenient as doing a grep of your `^APP_` vars, but one way to avoid the physical file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by supplying multiple compose files, as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files). In your case the first one is a physical `docker-compose.yml` and the second one a Compose containing only the environment variables for the needed service. Obviously, env variables must be properly formatted, so a `sed` that prepends the string    `-` is necessary because they are added as YAML list.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f <(printf "services:
  your_service:
    environment:\n$(env | grep ^APP_ | sed -e "s/^/    - /")"
) up
```

This is how Docker behaves:

> When you supply multiple files, Compose combines them into a single configuration. Compose builds the configuration in the order you supply the files. Subsequent files override and add to their predecessors